# In Unity I'm trying to "fake float" my character controller, gravity turned off but something is still pulling downwards (Y direction)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Should mention I'm trying to make it work with C# but open to JS options.

So my idea is for my CharacterController to hit my water object which has a OnTriggerEnter function attached, causing 3 things to happen:

1. My animation changes from idle/walking/running to TreadWater (works fine, just needs tweaking)
2. Turn gravity off of the rigidbody (the char controller)
3. Set the Y position of the rigidbody to the surface of the water so that it appears to be floating

`CharacterController controller;
Animator Animator;
bool WaterImpact;
GameObject WaterProDaytime;
public Rigidbody Model;

void Start() {
    Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    Model = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

    Model.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    Model.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;



}
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
    if (col.gameObject.name == "WaterProDaytime") {
        WaterImpact = true;

        //PlayerController.gravity = 0;
    }

    Debug.Log (col.gameObject.name);
    Debug.Log (WaterImpact);
}
void Update() {

    if (WaterImpact) {

        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, -1.4f, transform.position.z);

        //Debug.Log (PlayerController.gravity);
        //Debug.Log ("WaterHit");

    }
}`

Tried using a `void Update()`function and setting the position every update too and while that does it work, there appears to be an opposing force causing the character to "jitter" very rapidly.

Ideally I would just like all opposing forces to be turned off and the `transform.position.y` to be locked to the surface of the water.

Been looking at this for 2 days, would appreciate any help whatsoever but please go easy on me, very new to Unity and C#

Cheers

Edited script.

Comment: Please post screenshot of the Character Controller Transform in the Editor. Does your `OnTriggerEnter` even work? You can put `Debug.Log` it and outside the `if` statement and let me know the result.

Comment: OnTriggerEnter works fine, triggers the animation set change and does change the gravity to `0` if I use `PlayerController.gravity = 0;`, `PlayerController` is another script which has the gravity defined as 12 @Programmer

Comment: On what condition does your gravity turn back to 12? Isn't it just rapidly switching back and forth between 0 and 12?

Comment: This may very well have been the problem, turned off all gravity modifications and just setting the Y position worked @MXD

Answer (score 1):

May it simply be caused by the `this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = true;` line?
I guess from your explanation point **2.** that it should be `this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;` instead.

Also please note you can simply call `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` instead of `this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`.

Last point: when dealing with physics, try to always stick with the provided engine tools. `transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, -1.5f, transform.position.z);` line can mess up with physics as you change the position of the object arbitrarily. Calling `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(new Vector3 (transform.position.x, -1.5f, transform.position.z));` is much safer.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: *For most things* you can get rid of `this.`, the only time it's needed is if a class field and either a method parameter or a local variable have the same name.

Comment: I turned off all gravity modifications, left it for the night (I swear I didn't touch a thing) and when I tried it again this morning it was working and it was working.

However when I tried to change the transform method as you suggested to `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(new Vector3 (transform.position.x, -1.5f, transform.position.z));', it no longer sets the Y position of my controller correctly? @Kardux

Comment: @Draco18s Agreed `this` can be used in that situation but I find it bad design since forgetting this keyword _(pun intended)_ can mess with your code... About the rigidbody `MovePosition()` method, it may be cause by other colliders you have in your scene: try disabling your controller collider while calling it and see if it works :) Also about things working when Unity is closed/re-opened, it sadly happens quite often: always a good thing to try to reboot it in case of doubt.

Comment: How do you mean disable it while calling it? Don't I need the collider to detect the impact of the water object? @Kardux

Comment: Something like `GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = false;` (note sure it's still a _CapsuleCollider_ by the way) and then calling `MovePosition()`.

Comment: No luck, used `GetComponent<MeshCollider>().enabled = false;` which did disable the collider on impact with the water but didn't solve the `transform` issue.

`transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, -1.5f, transform.position.z);` is the only thing I can get working but it's causing a lot of strange problems @Kardux Cheers for the help by the way, C# is a nightmare to learn

Comment: To be honest in this case this is mostly Unity than can be "hard" to learn (even if "weird" would be a more appropriate word I guess): this has quite nothing to do with C# :) If you are really stuck about that part you could always send your a sample of your project and I can take a look at it (according this is not confidential or protected IP)